# AWS S3 bucket CORS settings not fixing the error

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, error-handling, cors

on my AWS S3 bucket https://qr-code-page.s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/S3+Buckets/index.html (view in phone mode for optimal experience) Im calling an external link when clicked on the Send button.

This throws a CORS error in the console, even though I think I have added the proper CORS rules in the permissions tab.

```
[
{
    "AllowedHeaders": [
        "*"
    ],
    "AllowedMethods": [
        "GET",
        "HEAD"
    ],
    "AllowedOrigins": [
        "*"
    ],
    "ExposeHeaders": [],
    "MaxAgeSeconds": 3000
}
]
```

but this doesn't seem to do the trick, the error still persists. any recommendations on what to do next?

the ajax call looks like this:

```
function sendform() {
  var description = document.getElementById("problemDetails").value == 
  null ? '' : document.getElementById("problemDetails").value
  console.log('description = '+description)
  $.ajax({
     method: "GET",
    headers: {
  'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
  'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': 'https://qhtzkxv8aj.execute-api.eu- 
 central-1.amazonaws.com/Live/'
 },
url: "https://qhtzkxv8aj.execute-api.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/Live/environment="+getParam('environment')+"&function="+getParam('function')+"&location="+getParam('location')+"&tasktype="+getParam('tasktype')+"&subjecttype="+getParam('subjecttype')+"&description="+description,
success: function (data) { console.log('succes; ' + data) },
failure: function (data) { console.log('failure; ' + data) },
```

Comment: No point in adding a `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header on the request, because `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` is a _response_ header.

Comment: @jub0bs That is true. i tried it but already removed it as it wont do anything. still not sure why the cors is blocking it. maybe need te restart the server? no editing to the corse rules seems to do anything so I'm not sure my changes are applied to the bucket...

Answer (score -1):

I suggest you print the requested URL in the console and see if you can access that link directly, the CORS config above should do the work.

also check respond details under chrome network inspector in the dev tools

Comment: I might have found the culprit. not sure, but whenever I try to add the URL parameters the site denies access. might first need to fix that before CORS will be an issue. do you maybe know how to add redirection rules so I can use parameters in the bucket URL?